# solve recurrence relation using mathematical induction?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

solve recurrence relation $a_n = 6 a_{n–1} – 9 a_{n–2}$,
where $a_0 = 1$ and $a_1 = 6$ and Verify, using Principle of Mathematical
Induction, that $a_n = 3^n + n 3^n$.

ans: i have done so far...
put $a_n=b_n$
$a_n-6a_{n-1}+9a_{n-2}=0$
$b_n-6b_{n-2}+9a_{n-2}=0$
$b^2-6b+9=0$, $b=3,3$

general solution: $a_n=(c_1+c_2n)3^n$

Comment: Please check to be sure that I guessed right in interpreting your formulas and in supplying the missing value for $a_0$.

Comment: I fail to understand the "ans" paragraph. Aren't you asked to use **mathematical induction**? (Presumably, on $n$... So, the beginning of the proof should read something like "Let $n=0$. The property holds because... Then...")

Comment: @Did: He appears to have been asked both to solve and to verify, the latter using math. ind.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I've altered some of your edit $a_0=1$ and $3^n$ rather than $3n$

Comment: @Mark: You’re right. (And you and I were editing the $0$ into $1$ simultaneously after you corrected the $3n$.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I can read, thanks. My point is that the "to verify" part is direct and that I see nothing about it in the post.

Comment: @Did: Presumably because Sandeep hasn’t got that far yet.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott "That far" in the sense of "up to the end of the first line of the question they wrote" or in the sense of "not covered in the lectures yet"?

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Your edit of the question erased the end of the OP's text, which reads: `b2-6b+9=0 b=3,3 gernal solution:an=(c1+c2n)3n`. This is horribly mangled but at least shows what the OP tried. Erasing it might not have been a good idea.

Comment: @Did: That far in answering the two-part question. Yes, you and I can see that the two parts are independent, but that may not be immediately apparent to the OP, or he may feel that it’s better on general principles to take the parts in order.

Comment: @Did: The erasure was completely unintentional. I’m not sure what happened: I don’t recall even seeing the lines that I apparently erased.

Comment: @Sandeep As I said above, the "ans" paragraph of your post when I first read it made little sense. But the full "ans" paragraph as you wrote it yourself (and as it is now restored) is indeed the beginning of the solution (simply, now, I do not discern what is preventing you to continue after this correct beginning and I feel you could have been more explicit about *that*).

Answer (score 3):

It makes no sense to ‘put $a_n=b_n$’ when you have no $b_n$ in the problem. What you wanted is the auxiliary equation $b^2-6b+9=0$, which you correctly solved to find the general solution

$$a_n=(c_1+c_2n)3^n\tag{1}$$

for some constants $c_1$ and $c_2$. You determine those by using the known values of $a_0$ and $a_1$: when $n=0$ equation $(1)$ becomes

$$1=a_0=(c_0+c_2\cdot0)\cdot3^0\;,\tag{2}$$

and when $n=1$ it becomes

$$6=a_1=(c_1+c_2\cdot1)\cdot3^1\;.\tag{3}$$

Now simplify $(2)$ and $(3)$ and solve for $c_1$ and $c_2$ to finish deriving the solution.

To verify it by mathematical induction you must do three things:

1. verify that $3^0+0\cdot3^0=a_0$, i.e., that the formula gives the correct value when $n=0$;
2. verify that $3^1+1\cdot3^1=a_1$, i.e., that the formula gives the correct value when $n=0$; and
3. show that if $n\ge 2$ and $a_k=3^k+k3^k$ for $k=0,1,\ldots,n-1$, then $a_n=3^n+n3^n$.

(1) and (2) are the basis steps of your induction, and (3) is the induction step: in it you’re showing that if the expression $3^k+k3^k$ gives the right value for $a_k$ for all $k<n$, then it also gives the correct value for $a_n$. In carrying out this step you’ll use the recurrence that defines the sequence.

Answer (score 1):

If $n=0$ then $a_{0}=1$ and $3^{0}+0=1$ so the formula agrees here.

$a_{1}=6$ by definition and $3^{1}+1\cdot3^{1}=6$ so it is true for $n=1$. Assume this is true for all $k\le n$. We now show this for $n+1$.

$a_{n+1}=6a_{n}-9a_{n-1}=6\big(3^{n}+n3^{n}\big)-9\big(3^{n-1}+(n-1)3^{n-1}\big)$

$=6\cdot3^{n}+6n\cdot3^{n}-9\cdot3^{n-1}-9(n-1)3^{n-1}=2\cdot3^{n+1}+2n\cdot3^{n+1}-3^{n+1}-(n-1)\cdot 3^{n+1}=3^{n+1}+(n+1)\cdot3^{n+1}$.